# How can I authenticate a user with a query parameter on any url?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

Let's say the user lands on `https://example.com/any/page?token=hhdo28h3do782`.

What's the recommended way to authenticate and login a user with the query string?

I was thinking about creating some sort of catch-all view (I'd also like to know how to do this :D) that calls `authenticate()`. Then I would have in place a custom backend that would authenticate the user.

Is this the ideal way to achieve what I want?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to [create a custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) that validates api keys.

In this example, the `request` is **checked for a valid token automatically**. You don't need to modify and of your views at all. This is because it includes custom middleware that authenticates the user.

*For brevity, I'm assuming that the valid user tokens are stored in a model that is foreign keyed to the django `auth.User` model.*

```py
# my_project/authentication_backends.py
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import AuthenticationMiddleware

TOKEN_QUERY_PARAM = "token"

class TokenMiddleware(AuthenticationMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            token = request.GET[TOKEN_QUERY_PARAM]
        except KeyError:
            # A token isn't included in the query params
            return

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Here you can check that the authenticated user has the same `token` value
            # as the one in the request. Otherwise, logout the already authenticated
            # user.
            if request.user.token.key == token:
                return
            else:
                auth.logout(request)

        user = auth.authenticate(request, token=token)
        if user:
            # The token is valid. Save the user to the request and session.
            request.user = user
            auth.login(request, user)

class TokenBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        if not token:
            return None

        try:
            return User.objects.get(token__key=token)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # A user with that token does not exist
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Now, you can add the paths to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` and `MIDDLEWARE` in your `settings.py` in addition to any existing backends or middleware you may already have. If you're using the defaults, it would look like this:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",

    # This is the dotted path to your backend class. For this example,
    # I'm pretending that the class is in the file:
    #     my_project/authentication_backends.py
    "my_project.authentication_backends.TokenMiddleware",

    # ...
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "my_project.authentication_backends.TokenBackend",
]
```

Comment: Oh interesting, is `authenticate` called on every single request automatically by Django? I guess not since, the CustomBackend I have in my project right now isn't called on every request.

Comment: @maximedupre is the user already authenticated and stored in the session? I think the user is authenticated on every request unless they're already logged in and saved in the request session.

Comment: The middleware simply attaches the user object to the request if he is logged in, it does not try to authenticate it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: @maximedupre I'm sorry, you're correct. I've updated my answer with custom middleware to handle the authentication when a `token=...` query param is present.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and also enabled the [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) mechanism in your project. If so, go ahead with this,

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


class QueryParamAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    query_param_name = 'token'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.query_params.get(self.query_param_name)
        if token:
            return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
        return None
```

and then, change DRF  **`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`** as

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'dotted.path.to.QueryParamAuthentication'
    ),
    # rest of your DRF settings...

}
```

#### Update

to do this without DRF, you have to write *custom model backend* (which is a bit lengthy topic)

**Refer**: [**Writing an authentication backend**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am not using Django REST Framework, just the standard Django. Do you know how to achieve the same in "normal" Django?

Comment: You need to write *custom auth backend*. Check out the reference in my answer.

Comment: I know how to build a custom auth backend. What I don't know is how to authenticate a user on any/all url with a query string.

Answer (score 1):

So, start with a way of managing your tokens. Here's a basic model:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expires = models.DateTimeField()
```

A custom authentication backend can be produced to check the validity of the tokens:

```
class TokenAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        try:
            token = Token.objects.get(code=token, expires__gte=now())
        except Token.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            return token.user
```

If you're using class-based views, you could write a mixin that checks for the presence of the token then does your authentication logic:

```
class UrlTokenAuthenticationMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'token' in request.GET:
            user = authenticate(request, request.GET['token'])
            if user:
                login(request, user)
        return super(UrlTokenAuthenticationMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

To use this on a given view, just declare your views as follows:

```
class MyView(UrlTokenAuthenticationMixin, TemplateView):
    # view code here
```

For example.

An alternative way to implement this as a blanket catch-all would be to use middleware rather than a mixin:

```
class TokenAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if 'token' in request.GET:
            user = authenticate(request, request.GET['token'])
            if user:
                login(request, user)
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Comment: Hi, this seems like a good approach. Is it possible to do this with function-based views? Also, I understand how to implement this for one view, but how would I got about it to implement it for all/any urls? Would I have to add the mixin (in the class of class-based views) to all the views? Or is there a generic way to catch all incoming request? Thanks!

Comment: Probably the most generic, set and forget way is to use middleware rather than a mixin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/